# Retrieving value from firebase in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase

I want to retrieve the database value on firebase in an iOS application. I've already installed firebase on my iOS project but I've tried multiple times but it shows me errors. Someone can help me?

Comment: It is difficult to fix errors in code when we have neither the code nor the errors :-) You should post *both* the code needed to reproduce the problem and error(s) in full.

Comment: Also give your JSON tree , in addition to what @Carpetsmoker said

Answer (score 0):

This is an example f collecting something from the database:

```
let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { error, snapshot in

  if error != nil {
     print(error)
  } else {
     // Get user value
     let test_retrieve = snapshot.value!["name"] as! String
     let user = User.init(username: username)
  }

})
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the terribly vague question which is about a bunch of errors we know nothing about. It would be best to delete this answer and wait for the OP to provide more information.

Comment: Post your code so we know what's going on we can't help you while being in the dark